# Counting non-empty values in each column of a table

Tags: mysql, data-migration, counting

I am looking for missing data in a data migration project, and this report will help me immensely.

Given a MySQL table, I would like to count all the empty (NULL or '') values in each row of that table. The output would be a list of column names and a count of empty or non-empty rows for each column. This data is something I would manually compare to the source tables - manually because I expect few counts to match up *exactly* and column names are completely different between the source and imported tables.

I have about 30 tables to check, a few with 100 columns. I have direct MySQL access from my PC, but no access to run any scripts on the server with the database.

Example for TableA

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
'XX' NULL 'XX'
'XX' NULL ''
'XX' 'XX' 'XX'
'XX' ''   'XX'
```

The report I would want is (for non-empty counts with '' counted as empty):

```
Col1: 4
Col2: 1
Col3: 3
```

Comment: I solved it in the end with a PHP script. I loop for each table, then loop for each column in the table, then do a COUNT(*) for the table where the column is NOT NULL and a non-empty string or number. The results are put into a HTML table that copies nicely into a spreadsheet. It involves lots of queries, but works.

Comment: Just in case the solution is of any use to anyone else, I've posted it up here: http://academe.co.uk/2011/08/mysql-finding-counts-of-data-by-columns/ (I'll upload the original file and fix the syntax highlighting as soon as I work out how).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query for each table

```
SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(col1) as col1, COUNT(col2) as col2
FROM TABLE1
```

For getting all columns for a specific table you should run query

```
 select column_name from information_schema.columns where TABLE_NAME='TABLE1';
```

Results of this query you can use for auto generation queries like the first one.

Comment: Might be a lot of writing for 100 columns and more tables. ;) @Jason: but if you are familiar with a scripting language, you could generate it and submit it using tools like [Heidi SQL](http://www.heidisql.com/)...

Comment: That gives me the non-null count, which is a good start. MySQL treats empty strings as NOT NULL though (unlike Oracle). The destination system seems to freely use NULL and '' to mean "no data here" all over the place, so I can't rely on looking for non-NULLs to find migrated data. It's a good start though, and something I could knock together with a few search and replaces in a text editor.

Comment: I just might be able to punch a hole in the database server's firewall so I can write some PHP5 scripts on my web server. It seems that I am not going to be able to avoid scripting this.

Answer (score 10):

`COUNT` counts empty strings too, so your query should look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT( NULLIF( col1, '' ) ), COUNT( NULLIF( col2, '' ) ), ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I split the counts up into a series of queries in the end, to make it easier to automate (each row was a column count that could be displayed in a table cell).

Answer (score 1):

Count rows only which has values (Skipping Null/Empty rows)!!!

```
SELECT COUNT( NULLIF( Column_Name, '' ) ) from Table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
SELECT count( NULLIF( doctor_id, '' )) as doctor_count,count( NULLIF( chemist_id, '' )) as chemistcount from table_name WHERE employee_id="20";
```