# MySQL Iterate over column names

Tags: mysql, sql

I need your help in SQL. :)

I have a table which look like that :

```
Column1   Column2   Column3   ...
null       null       x        
x           x         null
x          null       null
x          null       x
...
```

I would like select the count foreach column and have a result like this order by this count:

```
Column1    1034
Column24   876
Column3    567
...
```

For now, I known how to select my column name :

```
SELECT column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'my_table';
```

And I know how to count in SQL:

```
COUNT(my_column);
```

I would like to know if it is possible to do that in SQL because I need to create a view in phpmyadmin.

By the way, forgive my bad english! ;)

Thanks a lot to those who take a time to help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting non-empty values in each column of a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217869/counting-non-empty-values-in-each-column-of-a-table)

Comment: There is a PHP script that does this, you can check it here: http://academe.co.uk/2011/08/mysql-finding-counts-of-data-by-columns/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html) to combine a number of your count queries, as follows:

```
(SELECT 'Column1' AS `COLUMN_NAME`, COUNT(Column1) AS Count FROM my_table)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 'Column2' AS `COLUMN_NAME`, COUNT(Column2) AS Count FROM my_table)
-- ...
ORDER BY Count DESC
```

If you need to build such a query dynamically (e.g. because you do not know the column names in advance<sup>1</sup>) then you can do so in your language of choice, using the result of your query on the information schema.

If your language of choice happens to be MySQL, then you can use its [SQL syntax for prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):

```
SELECT CONCAT(
         GROUP_CONCAT('(
           SELECT ', QUOTE(COLUMN_NAME), ' AS `COLUMN_NAME`,
                  COUNT(`', REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '`', '``'), '` AS Count
           FROM   my_table
         )'
         SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '
       ), '
       ORDER BY Count DESC
       ')
INTO   @sql
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

<sup>1. Having dynamic schema of this sort is generally indicative of poor design.</sup>

Comment: Hi eggyal! You solved my problem! Thank you very much!